# Built in Images on Matlab

Tags: matlab

Are there any matlab images that are built in like 'mandrill' that are at least 512x512? I need to load an image that is already built in with this size and then apply SVD compression, but I'm unfamiliar with any images that are of this size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rgb = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
```

Gives you a 650*600 image.

```
which('ngc6543a.jpg')
```

points you at a directory with a few more images and stuff.